# UnzipOpenFile (ZipArchive) is return uncorrectly when password is not right

Tags: ios, zip

i'm using ZipArchive library to unzip/zip files in my iOS application.

I noticed that UnzipOpenFile will not return false when password is not correct. Below is the sources.

Is there anybody has similar issue? (I have added my comments on it)

```
    -(BOOL) UnzipOpenFile:(NSString*) zipFile
{
    _unzFile = unzOpen( (const char*)[zipFile UTF8String] );
    if( _unzFile )
    {
        unz_global_info  globalInfo = {0};
        if( unzGetGlobalInfo(_unzFile, &globalInfo )==UNZ_OK )
        {
            //NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld entries in the zip file",globalInfo.number_entry] );
            return true; // i have to add this myself here.
        }
    }
    return _unzFile!=NULL;
}

-(BOOL) UnzipOpenFile:(NSString*) zipFile Password:(NSString*) password
{
    _password = password;
    return [self UnzipOpenFile:zipFile];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The password does not affect the ability to open the archive. The password is only applicable when you extract or add files to the archive. This is due to the password only applying to the files in the .zipfile, not the zipfile itself.

If you want to check if the password is correct, you have to attempt to extract one of the files. It will fail for an incorrect password.